# Java Netty Set source IP in sent UDP packet

Tags: sockets, udp, netty

I have captured SNMP traps/informs from my network (a mix of V1 and V2c) and I wish to write a camel pipeline to replay them in order to test my trap processing engine. In order to do this, I must resend the traps with the source IP of the original sender (since that is part of the criteria for identification and correct processing of a trap).

I thought I would send the resulting UDP datagrams using Netty (although I'm open to writing a stand-alone component or using Mina or any other approach, but the use of the Camel SNMP component does not immediately seem appropriate). I have implemented similar functionality in Python, and I needed to write to a raw socket. I have looked through the netty component source in camel and was not able to see how I might use it unmodified to use a raw socket.

Does anyone out there have an example of using netty with raw sockets that they could share, bonus points if it includes some reference to camel or better still if it calls out a way I can do this with something more high-level than a raw socket (ie a regular UDP datagram with some kind of modifier to set the source IP).

Many thanks

Comment: Since when does Netty support raw sockets? Java doesn't, how can Netty? Unless it introduces some JNI. Does it really do that?

Comment: Thank you - it had never occurred to me that java might not support a raw socket. I will try to write a C program and call it from camel exec and pass in the message over stdin.